# Is there a way for bitbake to display GCC (q++/qcc) compiler warnings?

Tags: linux, gcc, cmake, yocto, bitbake

I am working on a project that uses yocto project (bitbake) and an operating system using q++/qcc compiler. When I call bitbake  to build my packages, it does not show the q++/qcc warning messages in the console log as well as the log file.

The only way I can see these warnings is when I run bitbake --verbose , but along with it, I get all the other log processes information. Is there any way to work around this issue such that I can only see the q++/qcc warnings that were detected during the compilation of the C++/C source files?